# Edit View Model Binding with HttpPostedFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view, model, httppostedfile

I have a ViewModel:

```
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
```

In the `Create` view, I have an `<input type="file" name="file" />` that binds the `HttpPostedFile` to the model. So far, so good.

My problem begins when I try to develop the "Edit" action with their respective view.
I haven't problems at all to show the editor field for the string property `Notes`, that part is easy.

However, how do I show the `<input type="file" name="file" />` with the actual value in the `Edit` view? How do I to bind a byte array to the `File` property of the ViewModel? Is that the correct way? Is there another better solution? I'm stranded with this and would appreciate your help.

Comment: As a file input type is just for *uploading* and not editing a file in the browser what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't.** An `<input type="file" />` is not made for editing files, just for uploading them.

If you just want to be able to delete the file in the edit view try this (just an example):

1. Add a bool property `DeleteFile` to the edit view model
2. Add that property as a checkbox in the edit view
3. In your edit method check if `DeleteFile` is set to true and if so, find and delete the file attached to that record you are editing

And you could rename `File` to `UploadedFile` (so its a bit clearer). But thats up to you of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marc. But in the Edit view, the user must change the file, not delete it (the File is required). I think I'll have to put a bit of Jquery to control that... Thanks again!

Comment: You can show the user the file upload control so he can upload a new file and you replace the old file on the server side. And you can show the user that a file exists on the server but there is no way you can set the value of a file upload control (as this would be a security leak).

Comment: That's the point. I'll have to do that, show the actual filename (for example) and check in the controller if the File property of the model is null or not (to upload the new one and update the DB). Thanks, best regards!